# Check if background tasks are done

Tags: python, unix

I am running a lot of simulations in parallel on background using:

```
for i in range (a, b):
    os.system("python xxx.py &")

// To-Add: check if tasks are complete, then process the results
```

xxx.py calls another software.
Is there any way to check if the tasks are completed, so I can process the result?

Comment: Look at [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) - it offers far more control over subprocesses than `os.system`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) then you will have much better control over the external processes, including being able to start multiple processes without blocking, and check if they have completed. You will probably have to collect a set of Popen instances and use `poll` to see if they are complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess
import time
proc = subprocess.Popen('python xxx.py', shell=True)

while proc.poll() == None:
     print ( proc.pid);
     time.sleep(1);
```